How do Jehovah’s Witnesses interpret John 3:5-7 where Jesus says to enter the kingdom of heaven a person has to be born again from water and Spirit?
This article presents a view that to be “born of water and the Spirit” refers to spiritual cleansing. The re-birth, or the new birth, which means to be “born again”, is a spiritual rebirth. Whereas people once-born have physical life, a person twice-born has eternal life (John 3:15–18, 36; 17:3; 1 Peter 1:23).
I know that Jehovah’s Witnesses promote full immersion in water for adults who understand the implications of baptism and what it signifies. From your New World Translation, John 3:5 and 7 says this:

Unless anyone is born from water and spirit, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God… You people must be born again.

It is worth noting that whereas Matthew and Luke refer to "the kingdom of God", Matthew uses the expression "the kingdom of heaven" 33 times. The kingdom of God is central to Jesus' teaching. From a Protestant perspective, we understand the two expressions to mean the same thing.
Are Jehovah’s Witnesses who have submitted to water baptism deemed to have also been born from the Spirit, that they have been born again, or born from above, and are therefore confident of entering into the kingdom of heaven?
Or is being “born again” restricted only to those members of the 144,000 who say they have been anointed and have a heavenly hope?

https://www.jw.org/en/library/magazines/wp20090401/The-New-Birth-How-Does-It-Take-Place/

This question confuses me. I am an SDA and on this topic I believe we share a similar belief to JWs...we believe that being born again does include both physical and spiritual elements. Lesley, can you expand and explain this question more?

@Adam The purpose of this question is to get Jehovah's Witnesses to explain their view of John 3:5-7 about the necessity of being born again by water and spirit.

@Kristopher - That 2009 article is useful, but needs to be read in conjunction with the articles that follow on the new birth and rulership.

@Lesley correct

In the comment section to the OP question, Kristopher linked the Watchtower from April 2009, which contains a series of articles on the subject of what it means to be "born again" from a biblical standpoint, which gives an overview of how Jehovah's Witnesses show with the Bible, how they see that someone who is "born from water and spirit" belongs to the 144,000 mentioned in Revelation.
I will quote from it and other material in my response below.
1) Jehovah's Witnesses don't equate "entering the Kingdom of God" (John 3:5) with receiving salvation
In John 3:3 Jesus stated: "Unless anyone is born again, he cannot see the kingdom of God."

‘But,’ some may say, ‘are not these two expressions​—entering the
Kingdom and receiving salvation—​referring to the same reward?’ No,
they are not. To understand the difference, let us consider first the
meaning of the expression “kingdom of God.”
A kingdom is a form of government. So, then, the expression “kingdom
of God” means “government of God.” The Bible teaches that Jesus
Christ, the “son of man,” is the King of God’s Kingdom and that Christ
has fellow rulers. (Daniel 7:1, 13, 14; Matthew 26:63, 64)
Furthermore, a vision given to the apostle John disclosed that
Christ’s fellow rulers are individuals chosen “out of every tribe and
tongue and people and nation” and will “rule as kings over the earth.”
(Revelation 5:9, 10; 20:6) God’s Word further reveals that those who
will rule as kings form a “little flock” of 144,000 individuals “who
have been bought from the earth.”​—Luke 12:32; Revelation 14:1, 3.
Where is the seat of God’s Kingdom? “The kingdom of God” is also
called “the kingdom of the heavens,” which shows that  Jesus and his
fellow kings rule from heaven. (Luke 8:10; Matthew 13:11) Thus, God’s
Kingdom is a heavenly government made up of Jesus Christ and a group
of fellow rulers chosen from among mankind.
What, then, did Jesus mean when he stated that one must be born again
to “enter into the kingdom of God”? He meant that one needs to be born
again in order to become a ruler with Christ in heaven. Simply put,
the purpose of the new birth is to prepare a limited group of humans
for heavenly rulership.
Watchtower - April 2009 - The New Birth: What is its purpose

So "entering" or "seeing" the Kingdom of God/Heaven is only for those who will receive a heavenly resurrection - the 144,000 - and not for those who will receive eternal salvation on earth.
2) Why born from "Water"?

What about Jesus’ reference to water? Consider the events that are
recorded immediately before and after the conversation with Nicodemus.
These show that both John the Baptizer and Jesus’ disciples were
performing baptisms in water. (John 1:19, 31; 3:22; 4:1-3) This
practice became well-known in Jerusalem. Therefore, when Jesus spoke
about water, Nicodemus would have discerned that Jesus was referring,
not to water in general, but to the water of baptism.
The Watchtower - April 2009 - The New Birth-How does it take place?

So "born from Water" does speak about the physical act of immersion in water at water baptism.

Baptism is an outward symbol, or public display, that the individual being baptized has repented of his sins and made an unconditional
promise to God to do his will. That includes living a life of
obedience to God and to Jesus. People who get baptized put themselves
on the path to everlasting life.
Water immersion is an apt symbol for the change a person has made in
his life. How so? The Bible compares baptism to burial. (Romans 6:4;
Colossians 2:12) By going under the water, the person is showing that
he has died to his former way of life. When he comes up from the
water, he is, in effect, starting his new life as a dedicated
Christian.
What is Baptism?

So being "born from water" means "starting a new life as a dedicated Christian" for Jehovah's Witnesses. It's the individual's own choice to take the steps to get baptized. Being "born from spirit" however is NOT a personal choice.
3) How is one born from "Spirit"?

Before Nicodemus’ conversation with Jesus, John the Baptizer had
announced that not only water but also spirit would play a role in
baptism. He said: “I baptized you with water, but he [Jesus] will
baptize you with holy spirit.” (Mark 1:7, 8) Gospel writer Mark
describes the first time that such a baptism took place. He writes:
“In the course of those days Jesus came from Nazareth of Galilee and
was baptized in the Jordan by John. And immediately on coming up out
of the water he saw the heavens being parted, and, like a dove, the
spirit coming down upon him.” (Mark 1:9, 10) When Jesus was immersed
in the Jordan, he was baptized with water. At the moment that he
received the spirit from heaven, he was baptized with holy spirit.
The Watchtower - April 2009 - The New Birth-How does it take place?

So in fact, Jesus was the first to be "born again from Water and Spirit".

A Twofold Process
What do these baptisms reveal about the new birth? They show that the
new birth takes place by means of a twofold process. Note that Jesus
first got baptized with water. Then he received the holy spirit.
Similarly, the early disciples had first been baptized in water (some
by John the Baptizer), and then they received the holy spirit. (John
1:26-36) Likewise, the 3,000 converts at Pentecost 33 C.E. were first baptized with water,
and then they received the holy spirit.
Keeping in mind the baptisms that occurred on Pentecost 33 C.E., how
should we expect the new birth to take place today? In the same way
that it occurred in the case of Jesus’ apostles and early disciples.
First, a person repents of his sins, turns away from a wrong course,
dedicates his life to Jehovah to worship and serve him, and makes his
dedication public by water baptism. Then, if God chooses him to serve
as a ruler in His Kingdom, he is anointed with holy spirit. The first
part of this twofold process (baptism with water) is initiated by the
individual; the second part (baptism with spirit) is initiated by God.
When a person undergoes both baptisms, he has experienced the new
birth.

So being born from Water AND Spirit is understood to be a twofold process. The only exception in the sequence (first water baptism then baptism with spirit) that the Bible mentions is for Cornelius and his household (Acts 10) - this was an exception so as to show Jewish Christians that God through his holy spirit unambiguously confirmed, that Gentiles could become Christians. Their baptism in Water followed promptly (Acts 10:47, 48), so that they too were born from water and spirit - becoming part of the "New Creation".
So to your question: Are Jehovah’s Witnesses who have submitted to water baptism deemed to have also been born from the Spirit, that they have been born again, or born from above, and are therefore confident of entering into the kingdom of heaven?
As stated - the JW's view is that having submitted to water baptism does not mean to be born from the Spirit.
Submitting oneself to water baptism is by personal choice, being born from the Spirit is by God's choice.
It seems though that water baptism is a pre-requisite for God choosing one to be born of Spirit. Cornelius and his household are the only exception mentioned in the Bible for a good reason - God demonstrated without a doubt through them that Gentiles were approved by God to become Jesus' brothers - not only Jews. This exceptional sequence (first born from spirit and then baptized) was no longer required after this, as God had made his point.
If God choses a water baptized Christian to be born again (born from Spirit in addition to having been born from Water), it means that this one "tastes the heavenly free gift and becomes partaker of the holy spirit" with the promise to become partaker of the divine nature at resurrection, due to them being "partakers of the heavenly calling", if that one remains faithful during their entire remaining earthly life (Hebrews 3:1; 6:​4-6; 2 Peter 1:3-4; 2:​20-​22).
All dedicated Jehovah's Witnesses symbolize their dedication to Jehovah through baptism. They dedicate themselves not for the "reward" or free gift of salvation, but because of their Love for God. They fully lay their lives into God's hands, firmly believing that He will, in his Love, do as He pleases and what is right with them for all eternity. Only a few are later (after baptism) chosen by God to be adopted as his children, co-heirs with Jesus of the Kingdom (Romans 8:15-17), Jesus' bride/wife (Ephesians 5:25-27; Revelation 21:9), and Jesus' brothers (Hebrews 2:9–3:1).

In explaining how God prepares humans for rulership in heaven, the
apostle Paul used an illustration taken from family life. He wrote to
Christians in his day that they would experience an “adoption as sons”
and that God, therefore, could deal with them “as with sons.”
(Galatians 4:5; Hebrews 12:7)

These adopted sons of God and brothers of Christ, will rule with Jesus as Kings and Priests over the earth (Revelation 5:10).
According to JW's belief, those who have dedicated themselves to God through baptism (and/or will dedicate themselves if they didn't have the chance for it yet), and that have not been born from spirit, will remain on earth and subject themselves to God's Kingdom rule, with eternal benefits.

Indeed, rulership in heaven is set aside for some, but the benefits of
heavenly rulership​—everlasting life on earth and all its accompanying
blessings—​are extended to many. May you and your family be among
those who will reap the everlasting benefits that God’s Kingdom will
bring.
The Watchtower - April 2009 - Rulership for some, Benefits for many


As regarding point 2) which says "Therefore, when Jesus spoke about water, Nicodemus would have discerned that Jesus was referring, not to water in general, but to the water of baptism." ... Isn't it obvious from John 3 that Nicodemus thought Jesus was talking about physical birth:  "How can a man be born when he is old? can he enter the second time into his mother's womb, and be born?"

You say "someone who is "born from water and spirit" belongs to the 144,000 mentioned in Revelation." A January 2016 study Watchtower article says "The vast majority of God’s servants today do not have this heavenly calling."  It also says "From the first century until the beginning of the last days, the vast majority of those who claimed to follow Christ were false Christians." So most Jehovah's Witnesses are  not born from water and spirit. They can't cry out "Abba, Father" because they have not been adopted into Jehovah's heavenly family. Have I understood that correctly?

When Jesus said "born again" in his first response to Nicodemus (John 3:3) - yes, Nicodemus thought Jesus was talking about physical birth (John 3:4). Jesus' following response in John 3:5 - being born from water and spirit was to clarify what he meant.  Water from the context is in regards to water baptism. This is basically confirmed in numerous examples in the NT where it mentions receiving the holy spirit after baptism in water - with the one exception of Cornelius. Nonetheless, being born from the spirit doesn't work without water baptism. Tf born from water and spirit.

@Lesley - You've understood correctly. They can't cry out "Abba, Father" in the sense that they have NOT been adopted as Sons of God and therefore are not called Christ's brothers. That doesn't mean that they don't recognize God as their heavenly Father (God being their creator, ultimate authority and eternal sustainer of life) - Luke 3:38. Furthermore, the sons of God - Kings and Priests together with Jesus - will lead faithful humans on earth to a state where these humans will also become children of God - Romans 8:19-22. So eventually, also humans will be able to call God "Abba, Father".

@Lesley the phrase “one salvation 2 destinies” is used to explain.
